# batch process regular expression find and replace on folder and subfolders contents

Tags: regex, osx-snow-leopard, replace, batch-processing

I have a  folder with subfolders that contain text documents (hundreds). The text documents all require a find and replace. The regular expression I am using to find the text is:

```
^([A-Z])[\r\n]+(\w+)\b
```

This is being replaced by:

```
$1$2
```

How can I batch process this find and replace on a folder with subfolders?

I'm using a mac (osx 10.6.8)

Answer (score 2):

You could use sed for this as well:

```
cd /path/to/files  # make sure you are in the right directory
find . -type f -exec sed -i.bak 's/^([A-Z])[\r\n]+(\w+)\b/$1$2/g' {} \;
```

**Edit**: I just realized that the above is a Textmate search/replace string. For sed you'll have to use:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i.bak 's/^([A-Z])[\r\n]+(\w+)\b/\1\2/g' {} \;
```

This makes a backup of all files.

Comment: should this carry out the find and replace as well?

Comment: Yes, sed does the search/replace

Comment: I don't have a Mac to test on, but now that I think of it you will probably have to replace `$1$2`with `\1\2` in the replace string. Textmate uses `$1$2` but that won't work with sed (at least I assume that's the case on a Mac as well).

Comment: when I ran the command it created the .bak files, but did not do the find and replace. Files were not edited. Files in the folder are .docx, .md, .txt.

Comment: This will only work on text files (not .docx, and I don't even know what .md files are).

Comment: This gives me the following error: `sed: 1: "s/^([A-Z])[\r\n]+(\w+)\ ...": \1 not defined in the RE`

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using `find` and `perl`:

`find ./* -exec perl -p -i -e 's/^([A-Z])[\r\n]+(\w+)\b/$1$2/g' {} \;`

*Warning*: untested :)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I get the following error: `Can't do inplace edit: ./ is not a regular file.`

Comment: strange...how about with a `*`